# What would be the proper backend response for expired JWT token?

Tags: http-status-codes, status, http-error

So what I found useful is according to [MDN's HTTP Response Status Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) the status code that can qualify is:

1. 400 Bad Request
2. 401 Unauthorized
3. 406 Not Acceptable
4. 412 Precondition Failed

Now, I was thinking of using 401 but with `error.name` or `error.code` of `JwtTokenExpired`. But then I saw 400, 406 and 412. I guess 400 is universal, or probably too universal? That makes 406 or probably 412 is more like it.

But I'm not sure. People haven't asked this in StackOverflow. So I think it's worth to discuss it and know that there's a certain standard.

Answer (score 1):

This depends in your security level. For security reasons, some answers are empty of the crucial information if they are information not for developers.

For example, if you are working with a client that is developing a call to your API, you can use a complete response of the problem in a sandbox environment, while in production the information provided tries to reduces to 0, in order to not give any information to the possible attacker.

Said this, you could use `401` if your token works like a security key, or even better `428` (or `412`) since the precondition is not fullfilled. A `400` should be the most empty response for this scenario since only brings information that the problem is on client side. For full protection and no information at all, a `204` response would confuses any enemy, but this is only for your concern.

From the [RFC 6585](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-3):

> 428 Precondition Required
>
> The 428 status code indicates that the origin server requires the
> request to be conditional.
>
> Its typical use is to avoid the "lost update" problem, where a
> client    GETs a resource's state, modifies it, and PUTs it back to
> the server,    when meanwhile a third party has modified the state on
> the server,    leading to a conflict.  By requiring requests to be
> conditional, the    server can assure that clients are working with
> the correct copies.
>
> Responses using this status code SHOULD explain how to resubmit the
> request successfully.  For example:
>
> HTTP/1.1 428 Precondition Required    Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Now that I think about it. Every app should just have its own implementation of security. After all, this strategy could only work if developers agreed on an agreement. I've seen Salesforce use `401` with a custom error response, which seems to be standard after all.

Comment: @IrfandyJip that's correct. In a payment system I work, I use the same code but with different body. In production the body refers to an specific number ticket that handles the error and if someone ask for that code in support, can know the problem. If it's a security issue (like a token) there is no such log, since we try to reduce the server process in order to prevent DOS attack or flood attack. But sandbox is pretty verbal and explain almost everything to the dev.